# PHP Date - Weird date calculation

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I was trying to round down time to a whole minute (as part of bigger rounding mechanism). In my unit tests I figured something strange, this peace of code:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:00', strtotime('2018-09-31 19:39:45'));
```

result in:

```
2018-10-01 19:39:00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I **WAS** running this on **2018-10-01**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cb0dd98e9d540616d02ce2d5c00684800af8597

Comment: September 31? There is no such date.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte you are absolutely right. That was the problem :). It's just me trying to code at 5am and just being retarded. Can you put this as an answer so I can declare it as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime()` doesn't validate dates.

If you do

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:00', strtotime('2018-02-30 19:39:45'));`

Outputs

`2018-03-02 19:39:00`

So, the problem here is that you are using an "invalid" date, and PHP is summing up seconds.
So, the spetember 31 means september 30 + 24 hours (in seconds). When you run `date()` will get the date in seconds and showing to you the valid date, october first.

Comment: @ViaTech because OP specifically said "I was trying to round down time to a whole minute"

Comment: @Nick, hmm... Guess I missed that note, no worries and thanks for taking the time to explain, it had me stumped for a bit